# Runtime error wirth FLASH CS5

Tags: actionscript-3, runtime

I'm getting a runtime error when I reach frame three. however, the runtime error says it's on frame2:6.
**The code for frame 3 is:**

```
stop();
buy_cups.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buycups);
function buycups(event:MouseEvent):void{
    cash1 = cash1 - 0.25;
    cups=cups+5;
}
buy_ice.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buyice);
function buyice(event:MouseEvent):void{
    cash1 = cash1 - 0.25;
    ice=ice+1;
}
buy_lemons.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buylemons);
function buylemons(event:MouseEvent):void{
    cash1 = cash1 - 1.25;
    lemons1=lemons1 + 2;
}
buy_straws.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buystraws);
function buystraws(event:MouseEvent):void{
    cash1 = cash1 - 0.25;
    straws=straws+100;
}
```

**The code for frame 2 is:**

```
stop();
//stand.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, check);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, check);
function check(ev : Event) : void {
    cash.text.text = cash1;
    storage_count.text.text = storage1;
    lemons_count.text.text = lemons1;
    cups_count.text.text = cups;
    straws_count.text.text = straws;
    ice_count.text.text = ice;
}
shop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over_shop);
function over_shop(event:MouseEvent):void{
    shop.gotoAndStop(2);
}

shop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shop_now);
function shop_now(event:MouseEvent):void{
    gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

**The error I receive is:**
Warning: No libraries were linked as Runtime Shared Libraries (RSLs) because of your publish settings: AIR Android
[SWF] Lemonade-boy.swf - 942698 bytes after decompression
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Lemonade_fla::MainTimeline/check()[Lemonade_fla.MainTimeline::frame2:6]

If ANYONE has any idea of what may be, or is, causing this please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is trying to access something that returns null (aka isnt defined yet)

It needs to be loaded for that frame. Where is storage1 located? (that is frame 2 line 6 right?)

Comment: But I have it defined on frame 3 as well. And it's still giving me this bogus error.

Comment: You need to have it defined before frame 3.
(You will have to do this will all of those in check)